# Foreground Listener Issue on Huawei Devices with React Native OneSignal Integration

Tags: react-native, onesignal, huawei-mobile-services, react-native-onesignal

I've successfully integrated OneSignal into my React Native app, and it functions properly on both Android and iOS. However, I'm encountering an issue where the foreground listener does not seem to be working on Huawei devices. Need solution with this problem